# RememberMe Cookie set expirations time but on Firebug appears as Expiration as Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, web-config, remember-me

I'm using C# and MVC5 to create my own cookie using this code:

```
// Prepare the ticket
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Clear();
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = 
   new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, 
                                 "MYNAME", 
                                 DateTime.Now, 
                                 DateTime.Now.AddDays(10), // <<- Expires 10 days 
                                 true, 
                                 null);

// Encrpt the ticket
string encryptedCookie = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

// Create new cookie
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("MYNAME", encryptedCookie);
cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;

// Send the Cookie back to the browser
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

On the Web.Config I set the name to be

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="MYNAME" loginUrl="~/Account/Login"></forms>
</authentication>
```

But when I look the **Firebug**, the **Cookie** appears as "MYNAME" but the "**expires**" is set to **Session**.
And in fact, when I close the browser, the cookie disappears and when I go back to the site, I always have to login again. The same happens with all other browsers.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was setting the Expiration at the "Ticket" level but NOT at the "Cookie" level.

Adding

```
cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
```

..solved the issue !!

So the entire code should look like this:

```
// Prepare the ticket
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Clear();
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = 
   new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, 
                                 "MYNAME", 
                                 DateTime.Now, 
                                 DateTime.Now.AddDays(10), // <<- Expires 10 days 
                                 true, 
                                 null);

// Encrpt the ticket
string encryptedCookie = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

// Create new cookie
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("MYNAME", encryptedCookie);
cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;

// THE MISSING LINE IS THIS ONE
cookie.Espires = ticket.Expiration;   // <<- Uses current Ticket Expiration

// Send the Cookie back to the browser
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

How it goes with other browsers? Chrome, IE?
If it works fine there, then it should be working on FF as well.
If it doesn't work there then possibility is there is issue with code

Take a look on these articles
[FormsAuthenticationTicket expires too soon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881864/formsauthenticationticket-expires-too-soon)

Basic one
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/244904/Cookies-in-ASP-NET
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.ASPX

Thanks

Comment: They all have the same problem ..all are somehow getting their expiration set as "session" at the browser level. the issue is not my pool recycling but that the cookie expires when i close the browser. If I don't close it, it stays active and automatically logs in when I return to the site.

Comment: Ok Add Timeout in the config as well, and try.
Put it like timeout=1200 and give it a try

Comment: Nope, still not working. I had a small hope on that :-)